# Inclusive or exclusive ? L1, L2 cache in Intel Core IvyBridge processor

Tags: c, cpu-architecture, processor, cpu-cache

I am having Intel Core IvyBridge processor , Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz( L1-32KB,L2-256KB,L3-8MB). I know L3 is inclusive and shared among multiple core. I want to know the following with respect to my system

**PART1 :**

1. L1 is inclusive or exclusive ?
2. L2 is inclusive or exclusive ?

**PART2 :**

If L1 and L2 are both inclusive then to find the access time of L2 we first declare an array(1MB) of size more than L2 cache(256KB) , then start accessing the whole array to load into L2 cache. After that we access the array element from start index to end index with stride of 64B as cache line size is 64B. To get better accurate result we repeat this process(accessing array elements at index ,start-end) for multiple times, say 1 million times and takes the average.

My understanding why this approach gives correct result as follows-
When we access the array of size more than L2 cache size, then whole array is loaded from main memory to L3, then from L3 to L2, then L2 to L1. The last 32KB of the whole array is in L1 as it is recently accessed. The whole array is also present in L2 and L3 cache also due to inclusive property and cache coherency . Now, when I start accessing the array again from starting index, which is **not**  in L1 cache, but in L2 cache, so there will be a cache miss and it will be loaded from L2 cache. And this way there will be higher access time required for all elements of whole array and in total I will get the total access time of whole array. To get the single access I will take the average of total no of access .

My question is - **Am I correct ?**

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See section 2.2.5 in the Intel optimization guide -
http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf

(note that this applies for Sandy-Bridge, but doesn't appear as changed for Ivy-Bridge, which has only minor micro-architectural changes over the previous generation).

So regarding your questions:

1. For the L1 there's no question of inclusiveness as it doesn't have upper level caches to be inclusive-of
2. The L2 cache is **not** inclusive, meaning that there's no guarantee that a line residing in the L1 would have to be in the L2 as well. However on most cases it's **likely** to be there since it was probably filled into the L2 when originally requested by the core, and has a good chance to survive longer in the L2 since it's bigger (and therefore the evictions are better spread over more sets), and filtered by the L1 (meaning less evictions usually)

Also note that if your benchmark is accessing a data-set larger than the L2, it will probably fail to sit in the L2 (especially if you access it serially and exceed the L2 by more than the size of a single way), and you'd have to fetch it from the L3.

Comment: Thank you Leeor. Can you tell me how a miss in L1 is handled ? Will it check for data in L2 , then L3 or L3 directly in case a miss occurred in L1 ? Also, have another doubt, will there be a replacement in L2 or L3 when a cache line is replaced in L1 when a miss occurred in L1 and the new line is brought from higher cache.

Comment: A miss will look up the next cache level, L1->L2->L3.    When a Line is fetched it should fill all cache levels on the way - filling the L3 is compulsory since it's inclusive, L2 is not inclusive as we said but it's still a good idea to fill it, since the line may silently drop from the L1, so you want it replicated on the other levels.

Comment: @leeor was always under the impression that due to VM paging, with process mem > L2, it would be useful to page align allocations (and exploit locality by packing related elements in the same page). I'm being told that merely word aligning is sufficient and page align will not provide any further benefits. Your thoughts?

Comment: @alphazero, there's some sense in saying that for storage it doesn't matter since caches work in line granularity (so you only lose space on unused chunks within the line). However, data fragmentation is definitely a bad idea even in page granularity - you'll need more TLB entries (and stand a higher chance to be serialized by page walks), HW prefetching is not effective across physical page boundary, and you may increase the rate of conflicts on lower addr bits which may have negative impact on memory units. I don't think the L2 has any special role here, this applies to the entire system.

Comment: @leeor Thank you. p.s. if you have a blog, you should put it your profile. :)